# Algebraically closed modules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, terminology

Let $R$ be a (associative, non necessarily commutative, but left Euclidian say) ring, and $M$ a left $R$-module.

> **Question 1.** Does the following property $(AC)$ have a name? \begin{equation}\forall (m,r)\in M\times (R\setminus\{0\}), \exists n\in M,\ rn=m\end{equation}
>
> **Question 2.** Are there conditions under which $M$ extends to a module with property AC?

Comment: Modules with this property are called divisible.

Comment: No module satisfies this property, except the trivial one. You should at least assume $r\ne0$, but usually the property is assumed for non left zero divisors.

Comment: Sure ! Edited accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For integral domains, a module satisfying this property (for all $r\neq 0$) would be called a [divisible module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisible_group). For general rings, the definition diverges into alternatives.

I think that a good general definition for "divisible module" is the [second definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisible_group#Generalization) listed at the link, because with that definition, every injective $R$ module is a divisible $R$ module.

That would also give you an answer to your second question: every module embeds in an injective (hence divisible) module called its **injective hull**. Actually if I remember correctly, in Lam's *Lectures on modules and rings* there is another object called the **divisible hull** that also exists inside the injective hull.

In case you're wondering, this general divisibility definition coincides with the classical one for domains.